# What is the second time sequence column in journalctl?

Tags: linux, systemd, logs, dmesg, journalctl

I am trying to remove all time-date stamps and sequencing from my **journalctl** output

For example

**sudo journalctl -eu NetworkManager**

```
[  130.787316] user NetworkManager[713]: <info>  [1707206156.8193] device (tun0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
[  130.787563] user NetworkManager[713]: <info>  [1707206156.8195] device (tun0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
[  130.789674] user NetworkManager[713]: <info>  [1707206156.8207] device (tun0): Activation: successful, device activated.
[  149.870255] user NetworkManager[713]: <info>  [1707206175.8792] modem-manager: ModemManager no longer available
[  150.666436] user systemd[1]: Stopping Network Manager...
[  150.666601] user NetworkManager[713]: <info>  [1707206176.6984] caught SIGTERM, shutting down normally.
```

I can identify two time sequencing columns in the output

1. The column before **user**
2. The column after **info**

Removing the 1st time sequencing can be achieved by adding **-o cat** to the original

**sudo journalctl -eu NetworkManager -o cat**

```
<info>  [1707206156.8193] device (tun0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
<info>  [1707206156.8195] device (tun0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
<info>  [1707206156.8207] device (tun0): Activation: successful, device activated.
<info>  [1707206175.8792] modem-manager: ModemManager no longer available
Stopping Network Manager...
<info>  [1707206176.6984] caught SIGTERM, shutting down normally.
```

But I am unable to find a clean way to target and filter out the 2nd time sequence.

Also, what is this 2nd time sequence called?

The 1st can be converted to a time-date by adding **-o short** to original cmd, but I find no filter to address the 2nd.

**sudo journalctl -eu NetworkManager -o short**

```
Feb 06 06:52:56 user NetworkManager[713]: <info>  [1707206156.8193] device (tun0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Feb 06 06:52:56 user NetworkManager[713]: <info>  [1707206156.8195] device (tun0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Feb 06 06:52:56 user NetworkManager[713]: <info>  [1707206156.8207] device (tun0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Feb 06 06:53:15 user NetworkManager[713]: <info>  [1707206175.8792] modem-manager: ModemManager no longer available
Feb 06 06:53:16 user systemd[1]: Stopping Network Manager...
Feb 06 06:53:16 user NetworkManager[713]: <info>  [1707206176.6984] caught SIGTERM, shutting down normally.
```

Comment: Whatever's after the service/PID field is from the service itself. In this case it looks like Network Manager itself adds a timestamp to the logs.

Answer (score 2):

The first timestamp is the number of seconds since the kernel booted. It's written by the logging facility (I don't know exactly where in the chain). I think it's the same clock that you can see with `uptime` and the first number in [`/proc/uptime`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). Since it's managed by systemd, `journalctl` has ways to pretty-print it.

The second timestamp is something that [NetworkManager chooses to include in its log messages](https://github.com/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/blob/1.46-rc1/src/libnm-log-core/nm-logging.c#L710). As far as journalctl is concerned, it's just part of some long line that begins with `<info>`: the format of a log line is timestamp, user, process name, process id in brackets, colon, payload.

The timestamp from NetworkManager is the current time. It's the time from [`g_get_real_time`](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/func.get_real_time.html), so it changes if the system clock changes. It's the UTC time, so not the time in your timezone. It's the number of seconds since the Unix epoch (1 Jan 1970 at 00:00 UTC).

You can use `date` to pretty-print that timestamp:

```
date -u -d @1707206156.8193
Tue Feb  6 07:55:56 UTC 2024
```